# automatically update remote git repo whenever change is submitted into gerrit's git repo

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a git server A. Then I have a seperate Gerrit server B.

I am trying to implement such workflow:

1. Developers fetch code from git server A.
2. A developer commits then pushs to refs/for/ to Gerrit on server B.
3. A reviewer +1 then clicks submit, thus git repo on server B gets newest commits.
4. Gerrit somehow makes git repo on server A updated too.

I am stuck at implementing step 4. I have been reading Gerrit's official doc and looks like Gerrit itself doesn't do step 4 automatically out of box. What comes to my mind as workarounds are:

1. Have a person to manually sync server A with server B, by typing git push etc.
2. Write a post-operation hook for each potential git operations a Gerrit submit might bring in. So whenever a git repo on server B changes, hook is executed and changes on B are pushed to server A.

Is there any other way to make it happen?

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical use case and many people use the included [replication plugin](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/replication/+/master/src/main/resources/Documentation) for that.